# How to make the "Skip to Main Content" accessibility links work for a Community?

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, aria

See [What is "Skip to main content"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10981/what-is-skip-to-main-content) or e.g. [Skip to main content](https://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/it-accessibility-at-nc-state/developers/accessibility-handbook/mouse-and-keyboard-events/skip-to-main-content/) for some background on this mechanism. It helps keyboard-only users.

These links are automatically present in our LWC-based community which is great, but whatever configuration is needed to make them work well we are missing as the links are presently only this:

```
<a
    data-aura-rendered-by="912:0"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    class="forceSkipLink"
    data-aura-class="forceSkipLink"
    >Skip to Main Content</a>
```

How do we wire these up so they take the user to the first main content link?

**PS**

Searching in the JavaScript of a normal Salesforce Lightning or a Community page, I found this component definition that AFAIK is undocumented and it is not clear to me how it works unless something in the platform listens for `markup://force:skipToContent`?

```
(function s() {
    return (function evaledScript() {
        $A.componentService.addComponentClass("markup://force:skipLink", function() {
            return {
                meta: {
                    name: "force$skipLink",
                    "extends": "markup://aura:component"
                },
                controller: {
                    handleClick: function(b, a, c) {
                        a = $A.getEvt("markup://force:skipToContent");
                        a.setParams({
                            target: b.get("v.target")
                        });
                        a.fire()
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return {
            "xs": "I",
            "descriptor": "markup://force:skipLink",
            "st": {
                "descriptor": "css://force.skipLink",
                "cl": "forceSkipLink"
            },
            "ad": [["body", "aura://Aura.Component[]", "G", false, []], ["target", "aura://String", "I", true], ["class", "aura://String", "I", false]],
            "ld": {
                "skip-link": {
                    "context": {
                        "target": {
                            "exprType": "PROPERTY",
                            "byValue": false,
                            "target": "force:skipLink",
                            "path": "v.target"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "fa": [{
                "descriptor": "body",
                "value": [{
                    "componentDef": {
                        "descriptor": "markup://aura:html"
                    },
                    "localId": "skip-link",
                    "attributes": {
                        "values": {
                            "HTMLAttributes": {
                                "descriptor": "HTMLAttributes",
                                "value": {
                                    "class": {
                                        "exprType": "PROPERTY",
                                        "byValue": true,
                                        "target": "force:skipLink",
                                        "path": "v.class"
                                    },
                                    "onclick": {
                                        "exprType": "PROPERTY",
                                        "byValue": false,
                                        "target": "force:skipLink",
                                        "path": "c.handleClick"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "tag": {
                                "descriptor": "tag",
                                "value": "a"
                            },
                            "body": {
                                "descriptor": "body",
                                "value": [{
                                    "componentDef": {
                                        "descriptor": "markup://aura:expression"
                                    },
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "values": {
                                            "value": {
                                                "descriptor": "value",
                                                "value": {
                                                    "exprType": "PROPERTY",
                                                    "byValue": false,
                                                    "target": "force:skipLink",
                                                    "path": "v.body"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }],
            "css": true
        }
    }
    )
}
)();
```